# Rails 3 Joins Active Record query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

I am stuck at join two tables using active record 3.0

Table A
id   name 
1    xcv

Table B #a_id is foreign_key
id   date a_id
1    9/15  1

How to query using active record to get output as 
id date a_name 
1 9/15/ xcv

When I do

```
B.joins(:A)
```

in Model B than I get following sql

```
SELECT "B".* FROM "B" INNER JOIN "A" ON "A"."ID" = "B"."A_ID"
```

When I query it on our DB it give correct output but rails logger has wrong output

```
#<B id: 1, date"9/15/11", a_id: 2>
```

I want is

```
#<B id: 1, date"9/15/11", a_name: xcv>
```

Relation is as follow

```
A has_many :B
B belongs_to :A
```

Any help is really appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is

`@bees = b.includes(:a).all # this will join A and eager load your A's`

then on your view, you can output

```
<% @bees.each do |b| %>
  <%= b.a.name %>, <%= b.a.date %>
<% end %>
```

or work with it in a similar manner